How do I stop mmd tools from merging objects upon export?
I have a FNaF OC that I am trying to get to mmd. I have everything rigged properly (For blender, I guess), and everything moves as it should while still in blender. When I import the exported PMX back in, however, all the different objects have been merged and the model won't move. It's the same case in mmd itself as well. These are the settings I've used :
The file is available at https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UFYHeCFN3nCaMKejX8EQ16Q1NBQqqHjo/view .  I've been using Blender 3.6 LTS.

First of all, which version of Blender are you using? I heard there are compatibility problems with mmd tools and Blender versions 4.0 and above, you might have to use 3.6 or lower. Apart from that, how did you export it, what settings did you use?

I'm using the 3.6 LTS, and I'll screenshot the settings. All I've done so far is create new bone groups and rename some bones

I forgot to add, I parented the armature to an empty object as well

You don't.
.pmx (or .pmd, or .x) and .blend files are each capable of different things, and so support different features.  In particular, there is no conception of "separate objects" in a .pmx; everything is treated as the same object.  (The shader treats every .pmx as a separate object for purposes of the world->object transform.)
MMDTools, which is probably the most popular add-on to work with MMD models in Blender, is designed to make things a little easier for Blender modellers, and so every object that is ultimately parented to the MMD object (an empty) is exported with the file.  If you export and then re-import, there is no way to store what object is associated with some particular mesh in a .pmx; that data is lost.
MMDTools does support "separate by materials" in its toolbar tab, which separates objects into multiple objects by their material assignment.  If you need to store object data for import-export cycles, you could potentially assign different objects to different materials.
This idea, that .blend supports features that .pmx does not, and vice versa, is not limited to multiple objects.  For example, a subdivision modifier in Blender won't be exported the same way (it might get written to the mesh, not sure, but that's different than doing it after armature deformation); and, in terms of vice versa, UV morphs are not something that Blender is capable of doing simply, and MMDTools has to kinda hack Blender to get those to work.

I forgot to add, I parented the armature to an empty object as well

MMDTools expects an MMD model that is to be exported as a .pmx or .pmd to be parented to an armature, which is in turn parented to a particular empty (at world origin) that has some custom data.  An MMD model has some extra data that it needs (name and model description, IIRC) and MMDTools creates and handles that data by this empty and this parenting relationship.  (You should be able to see this empty by importing a working MMD model into Blender using MMDTools.)  Changing parenting of the armature could easily break exports.
But, this isn't necessarily the only possible reason that your MMD model won't move.  By changing names, you may have destroyed the relationship between the armature bones and the vertex weights to those bones.  Or, you may expect an MMD model with renamed bones to respect an animation referring to the originally named bones, when it will not.  To give better information regarding why a particular model is not moving, we would probably need a file, and possibly, the exact steps you're taking that lead you to believe that it isn't moving: like, export as .pmx, using a particular version of MMDTools and Blender 3.6 LTS, load that .pmx into MMD, load a particular motion.

This is the base file before all the renaming and reparenting.

If you haven't done anything to the file, I can't reproduce the problem, which is a result of whatever you've done.

okay, I'll send the edited file too. Sorry for being inconvenient. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UFYHeCFN3nCaMKejX8EQ16Q1NBQqqHjo/view?usp=drive_link

Okay.  I'll edit your original post to contain that link.  I won't be able to help you personally with troubleshooting that file because I'd need to install more stuff than I want to (for instance, getting MMD running again on a new computer....)
